# How can I convert Windows.Web.Http.HttpStatusCode to System.Net.HttpStatusCode?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have some Universal app (WinRT/WP) code which uses the HttpStatusCode from Windows.Web.Http. However, I would like to convert it to the System.Net version as the interface (which comes from a Portable library) requires it. Can this be done "safely"? Can I convert it to a value and then map it to System.Net.HttpStatusCode?

```
    using Windows.Web.Http;

    private HttpStatusCode _httpErrorstatusCode;

    public System.Net.HttpStatusCode HttpErrorStatusCode
    {
        get
        {
            // conversion routine here...
            return systemnethttpErrorstatusCode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Either cast it directly (or via an `int`) or make your own `switch` statement.

Comment: Can I just                 return (System.Net.HttpStatusCode)_httpErrorstatusCode;